# Interpreting camera calibration results?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I used OpenCV's findChessboardCorners on a few checkerboard images (40~) and about 27 seemed to find the corners accurately. How does one proceed from here? Do I calculate the reprojection error over just the correctly identified images? Is this normal to expect?

**Some of the correctly identified images -**

[image]

**Some of the incorrectly identified images -**
[image]

How I'm calibrating my images -

```py
import cv2 as cv
def calibrate():

    criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    objp = np.zeros((6*9,3),np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9, 0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

    objpoints = []
    imgpoints = []

    images = glob.glob('*.png')

    for fname in images:
        img = cv.imread(fname)
        gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6), None)

        if ret == True:
            print('Hello')

            objpoints.append(objp)

            corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
         #   cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners, ret)
            imgpoints.append(corners2)

            cv.imshow('img',img)
            cv.waitKey(500)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

    return objpoints, imgpoints, ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs
```

I have added the raw images if someone might want to give it a try.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRCKP.jpg

Comment: is cv. and cv2. equivalent? Typically people use cv2. prefix in Python afaik

Comment: Upload the raw faulty images to allow people replicating your issue.

Comment: @Micka he used `import cv2 as cv`

Comment: thx, I think he edited that to the previous version of the question

Comment: @Catree I have uploaded the raw images.

Comment: I've tested the images and I think that I know where your problem is. When learning to calibrate a camera I had this exact problem: I took some photos and was not  able to identify the chessboard because of the angles/lightning. Therefore I had a 'live' solution. The camera recorded non-stop and had as output the recorded image. If opencv was able to identify the chessboard, the output would be drawn and the original image stored. Similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViPN810E0SU/. Another solution was to take many pics and hope that at least 20 were detected

Comment: And how do you get the green lines and not a rainbow color pattern?

Comment: I wrote my own function to draw the lines I guess, that's why. Also, thanks - this is what I thought could be the problem. I'll try again with different images

Comment: Chessboards that appear strongly tilted in the image are difficult to be detected. It is known. But on the 4 failed cases, you should have 2 correct detections (see [my results](https://imgur.com/a/jbmUuHN)). If `ret` is `false`, do not add these points for the calibration process. Finally, the chessboard must be completly flat (no wobble) if you want accurate results. The calibration method assumes a flat chessboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this normal to expect?

No, your incorrectly identified images are strange. I think that you might have a problem with your calibration process. Could you show some code (e.g. `findChessboardCorner()` and `calibrateCamera()` calls) ?

> Do I calculate the reprojection error over just the correctly identified images?

You should calculate the reprojection error over all points, but first you need to fix your calibration process.

Comment: Could you please give it a try with `cv2` instead of `cv`?

Comment: it is cv2, i import `cv2 as cv`.

Comment: I have tested your code on some samples from the docs and the results were really good. I also played around with different image formats etc.

Comment: I will try again with different images.

Comment: Fyi I used  from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/data the images left01-left14.jpg

Comment: thanks, i will try - i think it could be possible that images from those angles don't represent a planar checkerboard surface. I checked my checkerboard and it has some waviness to the surface, so maybe because of it - but in some of the cases the points are identified completely outside the checkerboard, so I'm not sure.

Comment: i think there was an error in the way i was generating the lines, i used opencv's inbuilt function and it works fine.